# How to fix error :url_decode, base64_encode are not a member of ‘pion::http::types’?

Tags: c++, pion-net

I am building an application with pion 5.0.6. libraries. The file contains pion-net 2.2.12 functions which are url_decode , url_encode, base64_encode.These functions are not defined in new version pion 5.0.6. So what can I replace in place of these function calls.

```
 This is the error I am getting:
 error: ‘url_decode’ is not a member of ‘pion::http::types’
 return pion::http::types::url_decode(crs);
```

Comment: Looks like those are in [pion::algorithm](https://github.com/splunk/pion/blob/5.0.6/include/pion/algorithm.hpp#L38) now.

Comment: yes Dan  thank you for reply.